# how to change prop name of an object into an object using string param

Tags: typescript

I want to modify an object withing an object using a string param.

I got an object like :

```
  const myObject = {
    simpleParam: 'value simple param',
    objectParam: {
      dataIwant: true
     }
  }
```

I want to use a string as 'objectParam.dataIwant' to change the value.
In fact i want to do 
`myObject[objectParam][dataIwant] = newValue`

I've managed to do a function :

```
  changeProp(obj, propertyName: string, value: any) {
const propertyNameArray = propertyName.split('.');
if(propertyNameArray.length === 1) {
  obj[propertyNameArray[0]] = value;
}
else if (propertyNameArray.length === 2) {
  obj[propertyNameArray[0]][propertyNameArray[1]] = value;
}
```

}

The problem is that i don't manage to get a generic function which work with every string possible.

Do you got that ?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the object had 2 properties with the same name, with one nested inside of a property and the other one as a property of the object?

Comment: That would be weird, but we should respect the order of the string param.

Comment: Checkout https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get